# Unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

So, I've got this bit of code, for which I'm getting the following error.

> Parse error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

I'm sure this is a very, very simple fix, but I'm still a bit new to the world of PHP. Any thoughts?

```
echo '
    <li>
       <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
          <img src="'echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_tour_url', true);'">
          <div class="galDiv">
         <div class="boatTitle">'.get_the_title().'</div>
         <div class="boatPrice">'.currency ().$price.'</div>
         <div class="boatPower"> '.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_map_ar_address', true).'</div>
          </div>
       </a>
    </li>';
```

Comment: Does this ring a bell? `'echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the following code:

```
<img src="'echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_tour_url', true);'">
```

Like the rest of your code it should use the concantination operator `.` and doesn't need an echo statement.

```
<img src="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_tour_url', true).'">
```

Comment: Ask a stupid question . . . :) 

Thank you for the patience! This is what I get for coding while sick. I actually caught it, but not in time to delete. My mistake, and thank you so much! Sorry to bother!

Answer (score 1):

You need a period in this code on the third line. and remove the `echo`:

```
<img src="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID()
           ^
```

Comment: The echo statement shouldn't be there either.

Comment: True enough - I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo HTML. Instead use inline PHP if possible.

```
<li>
   <a href="<?php print get_permalink(); ?>">
      <img src="<?php print get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_tour_url', true); ?>">
      <div class="galDiv">
     <div class="boatTitle"><?php print get_the_title(); ?></div>
     <div class="boatPrice"><?php print currency() . $price; ?></div>
     <div class="boatPower"><?php print get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_map_ar_address', true); ?></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</li>
```

looping? sure.

```
<?php foreach($widgets as $widget): ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Excellent thoughts, and it actually helps with another problem I had with the code elsewhere. Very much appreciated.